# Responsive Navigation Menu - Not flowing back to original structure

Tags: css, menu, navigation, html-lists

I am working on a clients site and the navigation menu is not popping back to its original form.

You will see, if you open the website on a desktop machine, drag the screen so that it is mobile size, then move it back to desktop, the menu changes into a list format.

I dont know what piece of code could be affecting this so dont know what to paste.

I have a test version of the site here: http://leebollu.co.uk/stablebed/

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Lee

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, maybe its because its been a long day, but I failed to notice the display:block rather than display:inline-block on the mobile version of the site.

All done :)